# treeview and postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, postback

I have a treeview, and already the javascript code to postback the page. Because when i select the father , auto-select the children.

this is my html code

```
<script>
                                function postBackCheckBox()
                                {
                                    var o = window.event.srcElement;
                                    if (o.tagName == 'INPUT' && o.type == 'checkbox' && o.name != null && o.name.indexOf('CheckBox') > -1)
                                    {
                                        __doPostBack('LinkButton1', '');
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>

                            <asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:TreeView ID="HierarchicalTreeView" runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="HierarchicalTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged"
                                        ShowLines="True" ExpandImageToolTip="Fechar &quot;{0}&quot;" CollapseImageToolTip="Fechar &quot;{0}&quot;"
                                        ExpandDepth="1" OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="HierarchicalTreeView_TreeNodeCheckChanged"
                                        EnableClientScripts="true">
                                        <NodeStyle CssClass="text" />
                                        <SelectedNodeStyle CssClass="text" Font-Bold="true" />
                                    </asp:TreeView>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:LinkButton>
```

and in C#

```
HierarchicalTreeView.Attributes.Add("onclick", "postBackCheckBox()");
ScriptManager scripManager = (ScriptManager)Page.Master.FindControl("ScriptManagerMaster");
scripManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(LinkButton1);
```

How can i prevent from postback all page, and only the treeview???, so dont 'refresh' the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TreeView ID="HierarchicalTreeView" runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="HierarchicalTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged"
            ShowLines="True" ExpandImageToolTip="Fechar &quot;{0}&quot;" CollapseImageToolTip="Fechar &quot;{0}&quot;"
            ExpandDepth="10" 
            OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="HierarchicalTreeView_TreeNodeCheckChanged" 
            ontreenodeexpanded="HierarchicalTreeView_TreeNodeExpanded">
            <NodeStyle CssClass="text" />
            <SelectedNodeStyle CssClass="text" Font-Bold="true" />
        </asp:TreeView>                                                                     
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="buttonCheck" EventName="click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:button ID="buttonCheck" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" />
```

C# code

```
 buttonCheck.Attributes.CssStyle["visibility"] = "hidden";
            HierarchicalTreeView.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').click();", buttonCheck.ClientID));
            ScriptManager scripManager = (ScriptManager)Page.Master.FindControl("ScriptManagerMaster");
            scripManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(buttonCheck);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Ajax for this, e.g. place your treeview in [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx).

Try calling __dopostback function like this:

```
 __doPostBack('<%= LinkButton1.ClientID %>', '');
```

Comment: Try change the way you are calling __doPostBack

Comment: Its because linkbutton is not in the updatepanel. Try placing it inside of the panel.

Comment: Still not postback only the treeview.. Updated the code in the top

Comment: did with succes with this version, but now is always collapsing the nodes

Answer (score 1):

It is stupid to allow checkbox in treeview but not to have the event handler for it..this is a work around if you dont use SelectNodeChanged for any other purpose, try this, instead of clicking the checkbox directly, you click the node, but your user need to be told on this :)

```
Protected Sub tvCust_SelectedNodeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tvCust.SelectedNodeChanged
    Dim enode As TreeNode = tvCust.SelectedNode
    If enode.Checked = False Then
        enode.Checked = True
    Else
        enode.Checked = False
    End If
    tvCust_TreeNodeCheckChanged(enode)
End Sub

Protected Sub tvCust_TreeNodeCheckChanged(ByVal e As TreeNode)
    Try
        Select Case e.Depth
            Case 0  'parent
                Dim child As TreeNode
                For Each child In e.ChildNodes
                    child.Checked = e.Checked
                Next
            Case Else
                Dim cnt As Integer = 0
                Dim child As TreeNode
                For Each child In e.Parent.ChildNodes
                    If child.Checked = True Then
                        cnt += 1
                    End If
                Next
                If cnt = e.Parent.ChildNodes.Count Then
                    e.Parent.Checked = True
                Else
                    e.Parent.Checked = False
                End If
        End Select

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```